# Django admin: ordering inline based on FK'd property

Tags: django, django-admin

I've got a simple Django photography competition app that has three simple model definitions:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'people'
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Round(models.Model):
    theme = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    number = models.IntegerField()
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'rounds'
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.season.name+" - "+self.theme

class Entry(models.Model):
    rank = int
    total_score = models.SmallIntegerField()
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, db_column='person')
    round = models.ForeignKey(Round, db_column='round')
```

A `Round` has multiple `Entry` objects, and each `Entry` has one `Person`. One `Person` can obviously have multiple `Entrys` into different `Rounds`.

In the admin view, I'd like to be able to select a `Round` and see the details of the `Entry` items inline. This I can do with the following:

```
class EntryInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Entry
    fields = ['comments','person','total_score','image']
    readonly_fields = ['person','image']
    extra = 0

class RoundAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['theme','number']
    inlines = [EntryInline]
```

However, this sorts the `Entry` seemingly arbitrarily. I can use django's new `ordering` keyword in the `EntryInline` class to specify the ordering should be on the person, but this orders by the person `Id` property and not their `name` property.

How would I order this inline on the FK'd `Person.name` property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this in the `EntryInline` class:

```
ordering = ["person__name"]
```